# $\dim(V) = \dim T(V) + \dim T^{-1}(0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $T\colon V \rightarrow W$ a linear transformation between the  real vector spaces $V$ and $W$ both with finite dimension.

How can i prove that $\dim(V) = \dim T(V) + \dim T^{-1}(0)$.

I can't understand this problem and how to solve it , if you can help me please.

Comment: It's in every linear algebra textbook in existence under the name "rank nullity theorem".

Comment: It has a web page on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: Just note that $T^{-1}(0)$ is the [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) of $T$, usually denoted by $\ker (T)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a space $F$ such as $V = F\oplus T^{-1}(0)$. Consider the restriction $T'$ of $T$ from
$F$ to $T(V)$.

1. Let $x,y\in F.$

$$
T'(x) = T'(y)\implies T(x-y) = T(x)-T(y) = 0\implies
x-y\in T^{-1}(0)
$$but as $x,y\in F$: 
$$
x-y\in T^{-1}(0)\cap F=  \{0\}\implies x=y.
$$2. Let $y\in T(V)$. $\exists x\in V\,\,y=T(x)$. Let us write $x = x_0 + x_1$, $x_0\in T^{-1}(0)
$ and $x_1\in F$.

$$
y = T(x) = T(x_0+x_1) = T(x_0)+T(x_1) = 0+T(x_1) = T(x_1) = T'(x_1)
$$hence $T'$ is onto.

Conclusion: this proves the second equality in 
$$
\dim V - \dim T^{-1}(0) = \dim F = \dim T'(F) = \dim T(V)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. consider $\mathcal{A}=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k\}$ such that $\{T(v_1),T(v_2),\dots, T(v_k)\}$ is a basis of $T(V)$;
2. consider a basis $\mathcal{B}=\{u_1,u_2,\dots,u_h\}$ of $\ker T=T^{-1}(0)$;
3. prove that $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are disjoint;
4. prove that $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $V$.